# Sorting a dictionary which is exported to excel?

Tags: python, excel, sorting, dictionary

Ok, So I have a dictionary with values which are contained as lists, which is what I've been looking for...  I was wondering if there was a way to sort this which will also display the values of the lists in separate columns... I have used this code to split the values into different columns:

```
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for key, value in finaldict.iteritems():
                writer.writerow([key] + value)
```

Is there any way to make this sort the keys before writing it? Anything I seem to try either doesn't sort it, generates an error, or breaks the part where it changes the list into separate columns... So if you don't understand what I am saying for example lets say I have a dictionary

`finaldict = {'A': [2 , 1], 'C' [3, 3], 'B' [4, 3]}`

I'm looking for this in the excel file:

```
Parameter  Val1   Val2
A          2      1

B          4      3

C          3      3
```

But currently I get this:

```
Parameter  Val1   Val2
A          2      1

C          3      3

B          4      3
```

I'm grateful for the replies guys thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to the other answer (a bit cleaner, imho):

```
for key in sorted(finaldict.keys()):
    writer.writerow([key] + finaldict[key])
```

Comment: I agree, I checked this too and it worked.  I ended up using sort of a combination of both answers

Comment: @RobertoBonvallet yup, and in Python 2.x forgoes the creation of a list of the keys... (in Python 3 it doesn't really matter) but yup... `sorted(findaldict)` is the best for both versions...

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted` to return a list of tuples containing the key and value, then write that instead:

```
for key, value in sorted(finaldict.iteritems(), key=lambda: L[0]):
    writer.writerow([key] + value)
```

Comment: welp... that was easy... I tried sorted in the wrong spot before.  Also what is the lambda for here/ does this instance work in python 2.7 because it came up with an error when I tried this directly, but it worked when I deleted that piece of the code

Comment: @user2824448 Ahhh... yeah... that's a typo - it should be: `key=lambda L: L[0]` - it basically takes the first element of the tuple (in this case the key) to use as the sort key... By omitting it, it will sort by the key, then by the values of the values... (no big deal, but a bit more work than required to obtain the order you're after)

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense.  I think I'm going to go with @kevinsa5 's answer because it does seem a little cleaner and works as well but thank you for answering and thanks for explaining the logic behind it, I'm still getting the hang of python so I like having explanations!

Comment: @user2824448 good luck with things - hopefully you'll find Python as pleasant as most people find it :)

Comment: Thanks! It's quickly becoming my favorite language :)